# Script task changes are not saved in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am working on a SSIS package in Visual Studio 2019 to dynamically load a flat file into SQL Server using a C# script task (Visual C# 2017).

When I edit the script task and make some changes, save and build, everything looks fine. I did set a breakpoint in the script task, saved the SSIS package, built it and ran the solution.

While running the SSIS job, the debugger takes control and opens up the script task. However, I do not see my new changes in the debug mode. When I stopped the package and re-open the script task, my  changes are lost.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you are exiting your VSTA instance, this may be causing SSIS to not save your changes correctly. If you simply exit (x-out of the window) the VSTA window, even after saving, SSIS will not retain your changes. You must exit the file after saving it by clicking the "OK" button in the Script Task Editor window.

Comment: I am not directly exiting out of the script task. Once the script changes are done, I save the changes by clicking on the save button from the toolbar, then rebuild the script by going into the build menu and select Rebuild ST_dafdafdadf (whatever that name is) and I make sure it displays the text "Build succeeded" in the status bar. Then I close the  script task by exiting out of it. From the main window where the script task was opened, I click on Ok button and then go back to project and click on Rebuild solution. Once all done, I open the script task and I see that changes are gone.

Comment: When you are ready to exit the VTSA window, don’t close out of it but rather be sure to leave it open and then hit “OK” on the Script Task Editor Window after you have saved your changes within the VSTA file.

Comment: I am facing same issue, @cdbullard I tried exact same thing but it doesn't save the changes in script